# Missing packages in the package list

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I was trying to install a GUI utility for DNS along with some other packages like system-config-firewall and system-config-printer on my fedora 30 I've done the following actions to remediate this issue:

```
1) sudo dnf update 

2) searched info online (eg: 
   https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php124615-system-config-bind-not-found   
   and
   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=221036)

3) I was trying installing it directly from the internet (nothing found).
```

[image: install]

Also I found out that I could install this particular package along with the other ones mentioned above without any problems in Fedora 16 and up to 24 but those cannot be installed in Fedora 30.

**Is there any way to manually update the package list and add a resource for system-config-bind and other missing packages?**

Any suggestions/comments/critics are welcome,

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: That package is certainly there in Fedora 30 when I try to install it. Add the output of `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo to your question`. Can you install any of the dependencies like `gnome-python2` or `gamin`?

Comment: Yes I can install both **gnome-python2** and **gamin**. I ok I will add the **/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora repo**. But just for the note, I am using **dnf** instead of **yum**.

Comment: Both of those are dependencies of `system-config-bind` that come from the same repo. If you can install them, there's no reason that you can't install what you are trying to install unless there is something that you aren't mentioning. There is no difference between `yum` and `dnf` so that isn't an issue with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Interesting that `system-config-bind-4.0.15-16.fc29.noarch.rpm` is in the F30 repo and that there haven't been any successful [system-config-bind builds](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=265) in almost 2 years.